# Session timeout - Redirect user to same page on logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, redirect, session-timeout

In my Asp.Net webpage application when session timeout occurs the page will redirect to the login page and when we login again it goes to the home page. 
But I want to redirect to the previously active page (where the session timeout occurs) instead of redirecting to the home page by default.
Is there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: are you using MVC? If yes, there is inherent support for this. You just need to provide the return url in form of a query string like this /account/login/?returnUrl=/abc

Comment: Sorry I am not using MVC I am working on web forms

Comment: Then also you can follow the same approach and handle the query string parameter accordingly. This thing requires you to be very very careful as someone can tamper the return url and your user's credentials may be compromised. So make sure to check before redirecting that the address is local and not of any other website

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed description of mentioning the return url. How can I mention it?

Comment: i don't know much about web forms implementation. But basically you need to know the current url before redirecting to login page, append it as the query string to the login page and in your method where you handle credentials, return to the path specified by the query parameter.

Comment: please check below answer

Comment: Yeah that was my problem I can't identify that url where the session timeout occur. I am redirecting to the login page from Session_End  Event on global.asax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can do following thing

When session expires at that time you can redirect user from that page to logged in page with below query string

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?url=page.aspx");
```

Where Page.aspx will be your current page name. you have to write this code on each page's load Event before if(!ispostback) condition.

and at time of logged in button click you can do

```
if (Request.QueryString["url"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["url"].ToString());
            }
```

after making query for user name and password before your redirect to default page.

Comment: But when session expires how to perform a redirection with the query string containing the current url.

Comment: **protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }**
This is my code which is used to redirect to the login page when session ends this is an event on global.asax file. In this event how can I identify the page name or url where the session time out occur.